# Postgres table with 35m rows slow queries. how can i improve the performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT count(c.id) as clickCount 
FROM clicks c 
LEFT JOIN links l on c.link_id = l.id 
LEFT JOIN user_agents ua on c.user_agent_id = ua.id 
                        AND ua.robot IS NULL 
WHERE l.user_id = ?

                                                                     QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=337670.79..337670.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3508.630..3508.630 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=448334
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..334057.39 rows=1445360 width=4) (actual time=0.041..3040.606 rows=6110334 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=448334
         ->  Index Scan using link_user_idx on links l  (cost=0.28..73.63 rows=136 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.093 rows=136 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (user_id = 1125)
               Buffers: shared hit=24
         ->  Index Scan using click_link_idx on clicks c  (cost=0.56..2208.66 rows=24710 width=12) (actual time=0.003..16.136 rows=44929 loops=136)
               Index Cond: (link_id = l.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=448310
 Planning Time: 0.512 ms
 Execution Time: 3508.683 ms
```

**3.5 seconds**

```
SELECT count(c.id) as clickCount, l.location 
FROM clicks c 
LEFT JOIN links l on c.link_id = l.id 
LEFT JOIN user_agents ua on c.user_agent_id = ua.id 
                        AND ua.robot IS NULL 
WHERE l.user_id = 1125 
GROUP BY l.location 
ORDER BY clickCount, location DESC



                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=495348.44..495348.49 rows=18 width=524) (actual time=1978.261..1978.261 rows=1 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(c.id)), l.location DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=23740 read=38820
   ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=495334.17..495348.07 rows=18 width=524) (actual time=1978.251..1978.251 rows=1 loops=1)
         Group Key: l.location
         Buffers: shared hit=23740 read=38820
         ->  Gather Merge  (cost=495334.17..495347.35 rows=108 width=524) (actual time=1978.231..1997.869 rows=7 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 6
               Workers Launched: 6
               Buffers: shared hit=153563 read=257052
               ->  Sort  (cost=494334.08..494334.12 rows=18 width=524) (actual time=1956.989..1956.990 rows=1 loops=7)
                     Sort Key: l.location DESC
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 4:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Worker 5:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=153563 read=257052
                     ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=494333.52..494333.70 rows=18 width=524) (actual time=1956.955..1956.956 rows=1 loops=7)
                           Group Key: l.location
                           Buffers: shared hit=153515 read=257052
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=22.52..494165.25 rows=33654 width=520) (actual time=42.709..1738.826 rows=872905 loops=7)
                                 Hash Cond: (c.link_id = l.id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=153515 read=257052
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on clicks c  (cost=0.00..476696.35 rows=6638735 width=12) (actual time=0.045..884.436 rows=5690344 loops=7)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=153257 read=257052
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=22.29..22.29 rows=19 width=520) (actual time=0.219..0.219 rows=136 loops=7)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=174
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on links l  (cost=1.53..22.29 rows=19 width=520) (actual time=0.050..0.186 rows=136 loops=7)
                                             Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1125)
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=22
                                             Buffers: shared hit=174
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on link_user_idx  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=19 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=136 loops=7)
                                                   Index Cond: (user_id = 1125)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=20
 Planning Time: 0.334 ms
 Execution Time: 1998.071 ms
```

**1.9 seconds**

```
SELECT sum(r.amount * c.revshare_influencer) as amount, r.month as month, r.year as year 
FROM revenue r 
JOIN clicks c on c.id = r.click_id 
WHERE r.user_id = 1125 
GROUP BY r.year, r.month 
ORDER BY r.year desc, r.month desc



                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=57546.34..62229.59 rows=22711 width=40) (actual time=2765.425..2914.399 rows=13 loops=1)
   Group Key: r.year, r.month
   Buffers: shared hit=1755012 read=8976, temp read=1198 written=1204
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=57546.34..61621.83 rows=32388 width=40) (actual time=2762.219..2936.577 rows=52 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 3
         Workers Launched: 3
         Buffers: shared hit=6407432 read=20902, temp read=4374 written=4398
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=56546.30..56816.20 rows=10796 width=40) (actual time=2749.492..2865.023 rows=13 loops=4)
               Group Key: r.year, r.month
               Buffers: shared hit=6407432 read=20902, temp read=4374 written=4398
               ->  Sort  (cost=56546.30..56573.29 rows=10796 width=52) (actual time=2681.282..2736.792 rows=318604 loops=4)
                     Sort Key: r.year DESC, r.month DESC
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9584kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8480kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8608kB
                     Worker 2:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8320kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=6407432 read=20902, temp read=4374 written=4398
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=361.57..55823.06 rows=10796 width=52) (actual time=113.962..2503.475 rows=318604 loops=4)
                           Buffers: shared hit=6407411 read=20902
                           ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on revenue r  (cost=361.01..27825.97 rows=10796 width=40) (actual time=113.683..358.398 rows=318604 loops=4)
                                 Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1125)
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=14271
                                 Buffers: shared hit=37228 read=15519
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on revenue_user_idx  (cost=0.00..352.64 rows=33468 width=0) (actual time=104.289..104.289 rows=1274414 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (user_id = 1125)
                                       Buffers: shared read=3485
                           ->  Index Scan using clicks_idx_id on clicks c  (cost=0.56..2.59 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1274414)
                                 Index Cond: (id = r.click_id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=6370183 read=5383
 Planning Time: 0.369 ms
 Execution Time: 2939.455 ms
```

**2.9 seconds**

table `clicks` contains 35m rows and table `revenue` contains 56m rows. the server is linode 32gb 16 core ubuntu.

*What i have done regarding this ?*

it's been mysql for me but haven't dealt with this loads of data earlier. i have been researching to improve the performance of this db. i have been tweaking the postgres for performance. there is 0 improvement (`work_mem,shared_buffers`) and tried understanding the query explainer which i am not very good at.

i am thinking of table partitioning / materialized views, but i have also read table partitioning might not be effective. or tweaking this query would give at least 50% of performance bump ? as these tables will pileup more in the future, what is the ideal way to overcome this issue ?

**Postgres Version:** 
`PostgreSQL 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit`

**Postgres Settings :**

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 5242kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 16
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8
max_parallel_workers = 16
```

Comment: Show table's DDLs (edit the question) in text form (no screenshots!). And show query plans.

Comment: Query plans from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) could be especially helpful! An easy way to share these is via: https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: thank you for the response. query plan is now added

Comment: The first one is mainly limited by your work_mem, so the sorting is done on disk. So if you increase work_mem, that should help. That will most probably help for the second one as well. The third one seems to be limited by the CPU. On what kind of hardware is that running? Partitioning is only a performance tool if (nearly) every query contains a `WHERE` condition on the partitioning key.

Comment: Consider replacing unnecessary outer joins with inner joins.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added settings and postgres version.

Comment: @mustaccio hey i have tried it reduces like 1sec or less

Comment: What kind of harddisk do you have? `random_page_cost = 1.1` only makes sense for  SSDs. But given the fact that you are mainly CPU bound, upgrading to Postgres 11 (which can also leverage parallel query) would probably already give you a performance boost (and increasing `work_mem` as mentioned before, maybe to 64MB or even 128MB - at least for the first two queries)

Comment: it is SSD. `SET LOCAL work_mem = '1024MB';` it says `WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks`. what would be the ideal solution to at least get the queries to run in 2 secs or below ?

Comment: Do you need the `DISTINCT` in the first two? That could save a lot if not. Also not sure if you have the query plans the right way around for those two?

Upgrading Postgres could be huge for all, for paralelisation, and more `work_mem` could then help if needed (would be interested in seeing new query plans first though).

Comment: Also, the second joins in the first two queries don't seem to be doing anything so could be removed for simplicity.

Comment: @Michael thank you. i have updated the postgres and removed the `DISTINCT` it helped alot in the performance. what can we do to improve it more. updated it with new query plans

Comment: As Michael already mentioned, the link to `user_agents` in the first two queries seems entirely useless and could be omitted. Also: do you have an index on `(user_id, link_id)` or just on `(user_id)`?

Comment: Great! Looks like some of the row estimates are pretty far out, an `ANALYZE` or `VACUUM ANALYZE` on those tables might help if you haven't done one recently?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Hey indexes are on both
@Michael after `VACUUM ANALYZE` first query not using the workers anymore :( it is now 5.8 seconds again. is it possible ?

Comment: @shakee93 would be good to see the query plan for that, to see where the time went. Also worth running it twice to see if caching is playing a big part

Comment: @Michael updated the query plan on the answer

Comment: Nice, thanks. I've put a couple of extra thoughts and links into an answer, would be interested to hear how you get on.

Comment: p.s. are you still including the second `LEFT JOIN` when running these? I don't have a theory for how removing it would help, but since it's not doing anything I'd give it a go in case it's somehow affecting the planner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that have helped so far (from ~10-15s to ~2-4s):

- Upgrading Postgres from `9.5` to `11.5` (allowed for paralelisation, possibly other benefits too)
- Removing unnecessary `DISTINCT`

A couple of further ideas:

1. Work out how to allow Postgres to choose [Index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) in place of the slowest of the Index scans taking the most time (note, the column order of your multi-column indexes is crucial).
2. They might be faster if you can encourage a hash or merge join in place of the nested loops. Better statistics on those columns might help, possibly even multi-variate. It's currently underestimating rows by 4x so may opt to pick a different plan with better info. Worth noting that you may also need additional sorted indexes to enable a merge join. More info on [extending statisitics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html#PLANNER-STATS-EXTENDED) and on [join operations](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgresql/operations).

Additionally, there are [several tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN) that make understanding and sharing query execution plans easier.

Disclaimer: I work on the most recent one listed, pgMustard.